# what is wrong: "value Parsers is not a member of package scala.util.parsing.combinator"?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I've got the above odd error message that I don't understand "value Parsers is not a member of package scala.util.parsing.combinator".

I'm trying to learn Parser combinators by writing a C parser step by step. I started at token, so I have the classes:

```
import util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers
object CeeParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
    def token: Parser[CeeExpr] = ident ^^ (x => Token(x))
}

abstract class CeeExpr 
case class Token(name: String) extends CeeExpr
```

This is as simple as I could make it.

The code below works fine, but if I uncomment the commented line I get the error message given above:

```
object Play {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //val parser: _root_.scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers.Parser[CeeExpr] CeeParser.token
    val x = CeeParser.token
    print(x)
  }
}
```

In case it is a problem with my setup, I'm using scala 2.7.6 via the scala-plugin for intellij. Can anyone shed any light on this? The message is wrong, `Parsers` is a member of `scala.util.parsing.combinator`.

--- Follow-up

This person http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5475 seems to have the same problem, but I don't understand the answer he was given. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Parser` is a subclass of `Parsers`, so the proper way to refer to it is from an *instance* of *Parser*. That is, `CeeParser.Parser` is different from any other `x.Parser`.

The correct way to refer to the type of `CeeParser.token` is `CeeParser.Parser`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Parsers is not a package or class, is is a trait, so its members can't be imported. You need to import from the specific class extending the trait.

In this case the specific class is CeeParser so the type of `val` should be CeeParser.Parser[CeeExpr]:

```
val parser : CeeParser.Parser[CeeExpr]
```

Comment: It's also possible to refer to the nested class using the syntax `scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers#Parser[CeeExpr]`. Nested types in scala are *path dependent* (meaning that the nested type is different for each *instance* of the outer type). The `#` syntax gets around this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the traitness of it. It would give the same problem if it were a class.

Comment: @Daniel is this true? I should try it. I thought if Parser was a class, then surely CeeParser.Parser would be an instanceof Parsers.Parser, so the import would work.

Comment: An import of `CeeParser` works, an import of `Parsers` doesn't. A class is not a package nor an object. You _cannot_ import things from it, only from instances of it. It's not that your solution isn't correct, is just that class/trait doesn't have anything to do with it.